# An error occurred: XXXLambdaFunction - Unable to retrieve TopicName attribute for AWS::SNS::Topic, with error message Rate exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am trying to deploy my lambdas to AWS, but getting this error.

```
An error occurred: AssignOrderLambdaFunction - Unable to retrieve TopicName attribute for AWS::SNS::Topic, with error message Rate exceeded (Service: Sns, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 79f1648a-90e0-5ebf-bb34-3f0993f6ca08).
```

I did not change anything in the serverless.yml. I have used this serverless.yml for over two years and have had no issues. Please help if you have any info about this error.
BTW I am not an AWS expert, just using it :)

Here are some details:

- I am using Lambda with NodeJs (Typescript)
- Using SNS and SQS to pass events across my services.

My serverless.yml structure:

```
 service:
  name: myService

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  memorySize: 1024
  region: us-west-1

  tracing:
      apiGateway: true
      lambda: true

  excludeDevDependencies: true

  iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
            - sns:Publish
        Resource:
            - Fn::Join:
                  - ''
                  - - 'arn:aws:sns:'
                    - Ref: AWS::Region
                    - ':'
                    - Ref: AWS::AccountId
                    - ':'
                    - Fn::GetAtt:
                          - orderPaidTopic
                          - TopicName

  environment:
    ORDER_PAID_TOPIC: ${self:custom.topicsArn.orderPaid}

custom:
  topics:
      orderPaid: ${self:service.name}-orderPaid-${self:custom.stage}

  topicsArn:
      orderPaid:
          Fn::Join:
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:sns:'
                - Ref: AWS::Region
                - ':'
                - Ref: AWS::AccountId
                - ':'
                - Fn::GetAtt:
                      - orderPaidTopic
                      - TopicName

  awsAccountId: ${ssm:${self:custom.stage}.aws.accountId~true}

  acmCertificateName: ${ssm:${self:custom.stage}.domains.api.acm~true}

  awsLambdaAuthorizer: ${ssm:${self:custom.stage}.aws.lambda.authorizer~true}

resources:
  Resources:
      orderPaidTopic:
          Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
          Properties:
              TopicName: ${self:custom.topics.orderPaid}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had various SNS topics in one serverless file or, better to say, had many SNS topics in one cloud formation stack. So what I did was, create three cloud formations (three serverless files), and I distributed them between three files